# How do you reference a namespace A in namespace B with TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, namespaces

In *src/models* folder, I have a big list of enums that I put in a namespace *Enums*.

*Enums.ts*

```
namespace Enums {

    const enum MethodType {
       Equal,
       NotEqual,
       ...
    }

}
```

In *src/typings-custom* folder, I have some interfaces (among others) that use those *Enums*.

*dto.d.ts*

```
/// <reference path="../models/Enums" />

namespace DTO {

    interface IRule {
       MethodType: Enums.MethodType
    }

}
```

The only way I found to reference my Enums namespace into the DTO namespace is by using the `/// <reference .../>` line.

Is it still part of good practices with TypeScript v2.6?
Is there another way?
(I tried with *import* but it expects a module instead of a namespace)

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The best way to manage your code is with modules, rather than namespaces. One thing to bear in mind is that [it is best not to mix modules and namespaces in TypeScript](https://www.stevefenton.co.uk/2017/08/stop-mixing-typescript-modules-and-namespaces/).

A module is any file with either an `import` or `export` expression.

Here is the `Enums.ts` module:

```
export const enum MethodType {
    Equal,
    NotEqual,
 }
```

And an example of importing the `MethodType` enum for actual use:

```
import { MethodType } from '../models/Enums';

interface IRule {
    MethodType: MethodType
}
```

You can also import "the lot", although beware of depending on things you don't need:

```
import * as Enums from '../models/Enums';

interface IRule {
    MethodType: Enums.MethodType
}
```

Ideally, you would load your code with a module loader, but you can also use tools to pack the whole lot into a single file if you want to persist with bundling.

Answer (score 0):

```js
export namespace Enums {
    const enum MethodType {
       Equal,
       NotEqual,
       ...
    }

}


/*-----*/

import * as Enums from './Enums'
```

Remeber that is better to change name because `Enums` is similar to a restricted word.

Hope this helped.

Comment: 1. Yes it helped, thank you!
2. Are you sure Enums (with this case Pascal case) is a restricted word?

Comment: Sometimes referring to object types you have to use Pascal case so is `best practise` to avoid using words similar or equal to restricted ones. However @Fenton implementation is more suitable than this one of mine, so i advise you to use his one!